# To find the date difference using derived column in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

**Goal:** I want to create a report showing each member experience since joining date with case condition showing 3 categories.

I managed to get the experience(in days) from joining date of the member. trying to derive new column categories say low, med and high. I have tried the below query but it is not working, The below query works for non-date values in reg_date column.

```
select m.member_id, m.first_name, m.last_name, m.store_id,
    (case when m.reg_date<='2018-04-01' then "low"
    case when m.reg_date>'2018-04-01' and m.reg_date<='2018-07-31' then "med"
    case when m.reg_date>'2018-07-31' then "high"
end, '%y%m%d') as category from member m;
```

Comment: reg_date is character data type store as yymmdd?

Comment: You are forcing us to guess when it would be simple enough to include the table definition and some sample data. please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

multiple bugs:

1. syntax should be (case when ... when ... when ...) instead of case for each 'when'.
2. second argument you pass '%y%m%d' is not necessary.
3. not a bug, but for the sake of clarity, consider using "else" for the last case.

   ```
   (case 
     when m.reg_date<='2018-04-01' then "low"
     when m.reg_date>'2018-04-01' and m.reg_date<='2018-07-31' then "med"
     else "high"
   end)
   ```